# Wordpress: Problem with entering a shortcode in an elementor

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following php function:

```
add_shortcode('mysubcategory', 'display_parent_subcategory');

function display_parent_subcategory($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'category_slug' => '',
    ), $atts, 'show_parent');

    $category_slug = sanitize_text_field($atts['category_slug']);
        
    // Get the specified parent category
    $parent_category = get_term_by('slug', $category_slug, 'product_cat');

    if (isset($parent_category) && !is_wp_error($parent_category)) {
        echo '<ul class="menu_subcategory">';
        display_child_categories_recursive($parent_category->term_id);
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid category slug';
    }
}

function display_child_categories_recursive($parent_category_id) {
    // Get all child categories of the current category, including empty ones
    $child_categories = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'parent' => $parent_category_id,
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    foreach ($child_categories as $child_category) {
        echo '<li class="cat_id_' . $child_category->term_id . '">
              <a href="' . get_term_link($child_category->term_id) . '">'
            . $child_category->name . '</a>';

        // Recursively call the function for each child category
        echo '<ul>';
        display_child_categories_recursive($child_category->term_id);
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
```

The problem is that after typing in Elementor, using the shortcode widget, the result in Elementor is displayed except where it is placed and in the upper left of the editor.This only occurs in the Elementor editor itself. The page renders correctly but it is annoying.

[view in Elementor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpL4J.jpg)

Maybe it comes from some problem in the php code.

Answer (score 0):

For shortcodes, if you are going to echo or output inside the function, you need to use ob_start and ob_get_clean to solve this problem, like this:

```
add_shortcode('mysubcategory', 'display_parent_subcategory');

function display_parent_subcategory($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
        'category_slug' => '',
    ), $atts, 'show_parent');

    $category_slug = sanitize_text_field($atts['category_slug']);
        
    // Get the specified parent category
    $parent_category = get_term_by('slug', $category_slug, 'product_cat');

    ob_start();
    if (isset($parent_category) && !is_wp_error($parent_category)) {
        echo '<ul class="menu_subcategory">';
        display_child_categories_recursive($parent_category->term_id);
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid category slug';
    }
    return ob_get_clean();

}

function display_child_categories_recursive($parent_category_id) {
    // Get all child categories of the current category, including empty ones
    $child_categories = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'parent' => $parent_category_id,
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    ob_start();
    foreach ($child_categories as $child_category) {
        echo '<li class="cat_id_' . $child_category->term_id . '">
              <a href="' . get_term_link($child_category->term_id) . '">'
            . $child_category->name . '</a>';

        // Recursively call the function for each child category
        echo '<ul>';
        display_child_categories_recursive($child_category->term_id);
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    return ob_get_clean();

}
```

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output